# Creating Dynamic LINQ Queries using Expression Trees

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am having trouble being able to replicate multiple .Wheres in my linq query using Expression Trees, I need this query to be dynamic since its a search feature.The database I will be querying eventually will get large so i need to be efficient and cant filter client side. I am at least trying to start by filtering by 3 of these columns. Below I added three of the ids im trying to filter by. I have read alot into expression trees but could use someones help to actually apply them to what im doing because they are confusing me.

```
    public int? heightId { get; set; }
    public int? ageId { get; set; }
    public int? genderId { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why do you need expression tree? Why can't you just use `Where` on these three columns, if you know what the columns are at design-time.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev because the user can select to search by that feature or not, so not always all 3 will be selected as search options. I hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not dynamic, because you know the columns in advance. You don't need to use expression trees as well. You can just apply the filters conditionally:

```
public Class[] FindByFilter(int limit, int? heightId = null, int? ageId = null, int? genderId = null)
{
    var classes = databaseContext.Set<Class>();

    if (heightId.HasValue)
        classes = classes.Where(c => c.HeightId == heightId.Value);

    if (ageId.HasValue)
        classes = classes.Where(c => c.AgeId == ageId.Value);

    if (heightId.HasValue)
        classes = classes.Where(c => c.GenderId == genderId.Value);    

    return classes.Take(limit).ToArray();
}
```

So, now `FindByFilter(10, 1, null, 2)` or equivalent `FindByFilter(10, heightId: 1, genderId: 2)` will return TOP 10 rows with height 1, gender 2, but any age.

Comment: wouldnt the very first .Where() that hits pull from the database though? i want to build the query out first then query the database

Comment: @Yaboy93 No, the query will only be compiled and and executed as a single query on `.ToArray()`, with all specified `.Where` conditions applied. You may want to read more about [LINQ and Deferred Execution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2007/12/10/linq-and-deferred-execution/)

Comment: thank you @YeldarKurmangaliyev so just making sure after reading the article so the query actually only executes when when you actually request the data correct, so hitting a .ToArray() or ToList() triggers db retrieval? so ideally you could have 20 wheres to filter the data as much as possible before calling the db correct?

Comment: @Yaboy93 Exactly :) The query is only built and executed when you **enumerate** it. It can `.ToArray()`, `.ToList()` or even `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have a class (or several classes) with a limited number of properties, probably less than a 100.

Somewhere in your code, this might be in the user interface, but it can also be after reading an internet page, a file, or fetching information from a database, somewhere in your code you'll have some input from which you can decide which `Where` must be executed.

So somewhere in you code, you have a function, that takes some input an returns the Expression of your where:

```
Expression<Func<MyTable, bool>> CreateExpression(MyInput input) {...}
```

The problem is, that we don't know how you get the input. What we do know, is that there is only a limited (less than the earlier mentioned 100) possible outputs. If there are erroneous inputs, than the procedure should either correct this into a best guess output, or refuse to produce the output.

Anyway, this long story is to tell you, that the code that should create expression is relatively limited. It is way better understandable, **testable**, maintainable if you would not make it dynamic, but create a non-dynamic function, even if you have a big switch statement with 50 cases.

For example: suppose the operator has to type the name and the value of the property that he wants to filter on. He might make typing errors in which case you warn the operator about the typing error

```
Expression<Func<MyTable, bool>> CreateExpression(string input, int value)
{
     // TODO: make the procedure case insensitive
    switch (input)
    {
        case "HeightId":
             return myItem => myItem.HeightId == value;
        case "AgeId":
             return myItem => myItem.AgeId == value;
        ...
        default:
            WarnUserIncorrectInput(...)
            return null;
    }
}
```

How many cases do you expect? Even if there are 20, this code would be much easier to understand, and to check for erroneous input than if you would use some magic interpretation to create your expression. After all: this magic interpretation should also check for erroneous input.

If in future a property is to be added or removed, then it would be fairly easy to maintain this function.

**Complicated Expressions**

It could be that you want the operator to combine expressions using some defined language, something like:

```
"HeightId == 4 AND AgeId == 10 OR ..."
```

If you would opt for such kind of inputs, you make your live very difficult. You would almost have to build some kind of compiler for this, checking all kinds of erroneous input. You'll have to detect when the operator means a property, and when he means an operation, or comparer. Not easy to do.

If you really want the possibility to combine expressions, consider using user interface elements like combo boxes, where users have to select a property, and type the correct value type.

Because the number of properties is limited, you can use a procedure like above to create an expression. The combination is done like below:

```
ExpressionFunc<TSource, bool>> CreateAnd<TSource>(
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> X,
    Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> Y)
{
     return (sourceElement) => X(sourceElement) && Y(sourceElement);
}
```

Again: even if you want to let the operator combine statements, if you use combo-boxes or similar, you can't get incorrect inputs, and the number of combinations is also fairly limited.

**Conclusion**

Although it is possible to create an expression from a string input, it would mean you'd have to create a compiler-like thing that checks for erroneous inputs. This would not be easy to understand, test, maintain.

As the number of requested Where statements is fairly limited, probably less than 100, consider using a function with a big switch-case